# Segmentation fault (core dumped) while running the program

Tags: c, data-structures, segmentation-fault, malloc, singly-linked-list

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<malloc.h>
//#include<conio.h>
struct list
{
char *value;
struct list *link;
};
struct list *arr[12];int val;
int hf(char *item)
{
int sum,i=0;
while(item[i]!='\0')
{
    sum+=item[i];
    i++;
}
return sum%12;
}
void insert(struct list ** arr,char *item,int val)
{
struct list *temp,*r;
r=*arr;
     temp=(struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
 strcpy((temp->value),item);
  if(strcmp((r->value),NULL))
  {
      strcpy((r->value),(temp->value));
      (r->link)=NULL;
  }
  else
  {
      while(r->link!=NULL)
        r=r->link;
      r->link=temp;
      r=r->link;
       strcpy((r->value),(temp->value));
      r->link=NULL;

  }
 *arr=r;

}
void main()
{
  struct list *li[12];int i=0;
  for(i=0;i<12;i++)
  {
      li[i]=NULL;
  }
  char *item;int ret;
  strcpy(item,"Steve");
  ret=hf(item);
  insert(&li[ret],item,ret);
  strcpy(item,"raj");
  ret=hf(item);
  insert(&li[ret],item,ret);
  strcpy(item,"Notes");
  ret=hf(item);
  insert(&li[ret],item,ret);
}
```

The above program is to implement array of linked list and im trying to insert string
as the value. When i am trying to run the program, there are no errors but it tells segmentation fault(core dumped)
so please explain the reason

Comment: Please note that your hf() function can return a negative value. It is a good habit to use unsigned types for hashvalues, sizes and indexes. Also: 2) main() shall return int, 3) don't cast malloc()s return value, 4) don't use too many unnneeded `()` parentheses. 5) use some whitespace, especially  around operators. BTW your `insert(&li[ret],item,ret);` should check if `(ret >= 0 && ret < 12)`

Answer (score 2):

The code

```
char *item;int ret;
strcpy(item,"Steve");
```

tries to copy the string literal `"Steve"` to an uninitialised pointer.  You need to allocate memory for `item`.  The easiest way of doing this is to hard-code a suitably sized stack buffer

```
char item[50];
```

You also have a similar problem inside `insert`.  You could solve this in the same way

```
struct list
{
    char value[50];
    struct list *link;
};
```

or you could dynamically allocate the correct size of buffer inside `insert`

```
temp->value = malloc(strlen(item) + 1);
if (temp->value == NULL) {
    /* handle oom error */
}
strcpy(temp->value, item);
```

In this latter approach, make sure to `free(node->value)` when you free that list node.  Note also that freeing of all dynamically allocated memory is currently missing from your program, meaning that you leak all memory allocated using `malloc`.

There is one more bug in your code - `insert` assumes that `arr` is a pointer to a valid `list*` but it is always `NULL`.  You need to update either `main` or the assumption in `insert` here.

Comment: even i tried item[50] still showing the same error. Is there any loophole in insert function

Comment: Your first comment allocates a 1 char buffer which you then try to write a 6 char string into.  Your second comment should fix the first bug but will fail in a later bug.  See my updated answer for details.

Comment: i tried struct list
{
    char value[50];
    struct list *link;
};                                                                                same error

Comment: Last bug now also noted in my answer.  Try reading up on use of debuggers.  That'd have shown you exactly where these problems were.

Comment: whatever changes took place in insert will be reflected  to li[ret] right? then how it will be null always.

Comment: I guess it won't be NULL always, just often.  It'll depend on whether `hf` returns a different index for each different `item` string

Answer (score 0):

change the following

In insert() function change the if loop

```
if(r==NULL){
    r = temp;
}
```

Change the structure. change the size of the structure for your need

```
struct list
{
char value[25];
struct list *link;
};
```

Change the variable item to

> char item[25];

**EDIT :** 
There is no need to typecast the output of malloc

Comment: not allocated any memory to struct list *r. so we have to  reference the new node. else when copying it will show segmentation fault